# OSX Cocoa App UI freeze and unresponsive after running for a period of time

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, user-interface, nstimer

My OSX Cocoa App is a test app which involves NSTimers, multiple threads, UART handlings and UI displays.

What happens is that in the main UI, there is a NSTimer running which displays the test time until a test completes. A typical test involves many test items which receive and send messages to UART, 4 UARTs to 8 UARTs. For 4 devices, it will involve 4 UARTs while for 8 devices, it will involve 8 UARTs. Each UART reading is being done by respective thread which reads into a buffer and subsequently stores the message in log files.

My test app basically has a main test thread which in itself will spawn to 4 or 8 individual threads based on number of devices. At the same time, there are a few NSTimers which checks the statuses of start/abort buttons, displays test times and etc. The UI is being updated smoothly for first few runs. The UI display mainly involves displaying test times, test statuses and a NSTableView which displays results for each test item. After say a few test runs, the UI starts to freeze or unresponsive. During the freeze, towards the end of the test, the NSButton which displays the test status just freezes at "RUNNING". This requires the user to use mouse to click on the NSButton for it to be updated to "PASS" or "FAIL". Although the UI appears to be freeze, the test is actually being run as we can see from the console log the NSLog messages.

I am debugging this issue by looking into the memory leaks and optimising the algorithm to no avail. 
Please help to give me some advice for me to fix this issue.

The test app is huge and hence, I'll post some relevant code snippets with our confidential details removed to save space.

```
-(void)onIdleTimer:(NSTimer*)timer
{
BOOL checkWell1 = FALSE;


if ( ! [appWindow isVisible])
    return;

if (!bTestRunning[0] && !pauseTimer1) {
    checkWell1 = TRUE;
}

if (checkWell1 == TRUE) {
    // UART data buffer

    char *pBuff1 = fetchRdBuff(0);
    char *pBuff2 = fetchRdBuff(1);
    char *pBuff3 = fetchRdBuff(2);
    char *pBuff4 = fetchRdBuff(3);

    if (!(pBuff1 == NULL) && strlen(pBuff1) != 0) {// && [uut1Check state] == 1){ //&& (uutSelected[0] == NSOnState)) {

        NSString *strBuff1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:pBuff1];
        NSRange range1 = [strBuff1 rangeOfString:RET_TOP_FIXTURE_START options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

        // Left button pressed to start test
        if (range1.location != NSNotFound) {
              startByMCU1 = TRUE;

            [self runtest:RUN_NORMAL wellIndex:0];
            startByMCU1 = FALSE;
            return;

        }

        range1 = [strBuff1 rangeOfString:RET_TOP_FIXTURE_STOP options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (range1.location != NSNotFound) {
            clearRdBuff(0);
        }
    }

    //Same goes for pBuff2, pBuff3 and pBuff4
    ...
}

- (void)testThreadMainRoutine:(id)argument
{ 
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

//Initiasation and etc
...


for (i=0; i<lineCount; i++)
{
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.001];

    if ([testThread[nWellIndex] isCancelled])
    {
        bTestStatus[nWellIndex] = ABORT;
        goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
    }

    // Is there any UUT available?
    bContinue = 0;
    for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
    {
        if (uutActive[j])
        {
            bContinue = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (bContinue == 0)
    {
        goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
    }

    while(bPaused == 0)
    {
        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];
        [self setTextResult:@"Pause" textColor:[NSColor orangeColor] wellIndex:nWellIndex];
    }
    [self setTextResult:@"Running" textColor:[NSColor orangeColor] wellIndex:nWellIndex];

    // Per Command Line
    CommandLine *cmdLine = [cmdArray objectAtIndex:i];

    // Run UUT independently from this command line
    if ([cmdLine independentRun] == INDEPENDENTRUN_START)
    {
        g_nIndependentStart = i;
        g_nIndependentStop = [self independentRunStopIndex];

        // Dispatch independent thread for each active UUT
        for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
        {
            if (uutActive[j])
            {
                g_itemCount[j] = itemCount;

                NSNumber *uutIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:j];
                [g_uutThread[j] release];
                g_uutThread[j] = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self 
                                                                 selector:@selector(testThreadUUTRoutine:) 
                                                           object:uutIndex]; 

                [g_uutThread[j] start]; 
           }
        }

        // Waiting till test abort or UUT thread finish
        while ( 1 )
        {
            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.05];

            // User press button to abort the test
            if ([testThread[nWellIndex] isCancelled])
            {
                // Cancel all UUT thread
                for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
                {
                    if ([g_uutThread[j] isExecuting])
                    {
                        [g_uutThread[j] cancel];
                    }
                }

                bTestStatus[nWellIndex] = ABORT;

             }

            // Wait until all thread exited, then continue remaining test
            bContinue = 0;
            for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
            {
                if (uutSelected[j])
                {
                    if ([g_uutThread[j] isExecuting])
                    {
                        bContinue = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        [g_uutThread[j] release];
                        g_uutThread[j] = nil;
                    }
                }
            }
            // All UUT thread exited
            if ( ! bContinue)
            {
                break;
            }

            //if (canUpdate) {
            // Select current test row
            if (itemCount != [self maxCurrentItemCount:nWellIndex])
            {
                itemCount = [self maxCurrentItemCount:nWellIndex];
                NSArray *objArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:nWellIndex],
                                     [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemCount], nil];
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(selectCurrentRow:)
                                       withObject:objArray waitUntilDone:YES];


            }
            if (nWellIndex == 0)
            {
                [testTable01 display];
            }
            else if(nWellIndex==1)
            {
                [testTable02 display];
            }
            else
            {
                [testTable03 display];
            }
        }

        // Test abort or UUT fail and aborted
        if (bTestStatus[nWellIndex] == ABORT)
        {
            goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
        }

        if (g_nIndependentStop >= lineCount)
        {
            // All test done
            goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
        }
        else
        {
            // Continue remaining test
            i = g_nIndependentStop;
            cmdLine = [cmdArray objectAtIndex:i];
            itemCount = [self maxCurrentItemCount:nWellIndex];
        }
    }

    NSArray *objArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:nWellIndex], [NSNumber numberWithInt:itemCount], nil];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(selectCurrentRow:) withObject:objArray waitUntilDone:YES];

    NSString *cmdName = [cmdLine valueForKey:@"cmdName"];
    NSString *cmdParam = [cmdLine valueForKey:@"cmdParam"];
    NSString *itemName = [cmdLine valueForKey:@"itemName"];



    // Clear returnArray
    for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
    {

        if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_SKIP) {

            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUnit:@"NA"];
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setLowerLimit:@"NA"];
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUpperLimit:@"NA"];

            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdResult:@"Skipped"];
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setTestResult:@"Skipped"];
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdStatus:SKIPPED];


            continue;
        }


    if ([cmdName characterAtIndex:0] == '_') // Per UUT command
    {
        // Repeat for all UUT
        for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
        {
            // whether UUT is selected
            if (uutActive[j])
            {
                ...
                    // Process test result
                    if (itemName != nil)
                    {
                        [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] testResult] testItem:itemName uutIndex:j uutStatus:SKIPPED];

                    }

                    continue;
                }


                // Before Item Test, save timestamp
                if (itemName != nil)
                {
                    NSString* timeStamp = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"\n%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: " timeZone:nil locale:nil];

                    [strPlog[j] appendFormat:@"%@ START %@", timeStamp, itemName];

                }

                // insert to UART log file
                char buff[1024];
                NSString *strInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d: %@, (%@), %@", i, cmdName, cmdParam, itemName];
                sprintf(buff, "\n[Host Executing Cmd]%s\n", [strInfo UTF8String]);
                [self uartDataLogging:j buffer:buff pureUARTData:NO];



                    [self parseCommand:cmdName parameter:cmdParam lineIndex:i uutIndex:j wellIndex:nWellIndex];

                     [self saveCmdReading:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdResult]
                             commandLine:i uutIndex:j lineStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus]];

                // Test Item
                if (itemName != nil)
                {


                        [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] testResult]
                                   testItem:itemName uutIndex:j uutStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus]];


                    // After Item Test, save timestamp
                    NSString* timeStamp = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"\n%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: " timeZone:nil locale:nil];

                    [strPlog[j] appendFormat:@"%@ FINISH %@", timeStamp, itemName];

                }

                // Fail Stop/Abort
                if ([[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus] == FAIL)
                {
                    if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_FAILSTOP)
                    {
                        // Stop this UUT test
                        uutActive[j] = 0;

                        if ([[uutBarcode objectAtIndex:j] length] > 0) {
                            [self InstantPudding_Done:j];
                        }
                    }
                    else if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_FAILABORT)
                    {
                        bTestStatus[nWellIndex] = ABORT;
                        goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    else // For all active UUT
    {
        // Before Item Test, save timestamp
        for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
        {

            if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_SKIP) {

                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUnit:@"NA"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setLowerLimit:@"NA"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setUpperLimit:@"NA"];

                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdResult:@"Skipped"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setTestResult:@"Skipped"];
                [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] setCmdStatus:SKIPPED];

                [self saveCmdReading:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdResult] commandLine:i uutIndex:j lineStatus:SKIPPED];

                // Process test result
                if (itemName != nil)
                {
                    [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] testResult]
                               testItem:itemName uutIndex:j uutStatus:SKIPPED];

                }
                continue;
            }



            // whether UUT is selected
            if (uutActive[j])
            {
                if (itemName != nil)
                {
                    NSString* timeStamp = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"\n%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: " timeZone:nil locale:nil];
                    [strPlog[j] appendFormat:@"%@ START %@", timeStamp, itemName];
                }

                // insert to UART log file
                char buff[1024];
                NSString *strInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d: %@, (%@), %@", i, cmdName, cmdParam, itemName];
                sprintf(buff, "\n[Host Executing Cmd]%s\n", [strInfo UTF8String]);
                [self uartDataLogging:j buffer:buff pureUARTData:NO];
            }
        }

        if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_SKIP) {
            continue;
        }

        [self parseCommand:cmdName parameter:cmdParam lineIndex:i uutIndex:-1 wellIndex:nWellIndex];

        // Process command return result
        for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
        {
            // whether UUT is selected
            if (uutActive[j])
            {
               [self saveCmdReading:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdResult] commandLine:i uutIndex:j lineStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus]];

                // Process test result
                if (itemName != nil)
                {
                    [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] testResult]
                               testItem:itemName uutIndex:j uutStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus]];


                    // After Item Test, save timestamp
                    NSString* timeStamp = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"\n%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: " timeZone:nil locale:nil];

                    [strPlog[j] appendFormat:@"%@ FINISH %@", timeStamp, itemName];

                }

                // Fail Stop/Abort
                if ([[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:j] cmdStatus] == FAIL)
                {
                    if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_FAILSTOP)
                    {
                        // Stop this UUT test
                        uutActive[j] = 0;
                        if ([[uutBarcode objectAtIndex:j] length] > 0) {
                            [self InstantPudding_Done:j];
                        }
                    }
                    else if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_FAILABORT)
                    {
                        bTestStatus[nWellIndex] = ABORT;
                        //[loopPool drain];
                        goto TESTTHREAD_EXIT;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (itemName != nil)
        itemCount++;
}

TESTTHREAD_EXIT:

if (bTestStatus[nWellIndex] != ABORT) {
    for (int i = nStartIndex; i < nEndIndex; i++) {
        if (uutSelected[i] == NSOnState && IPDone[i] == FALSE) {

            [self InstantPudding_DoneForAll:i];
        }
    }
}

[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:0.1];

for (j=nStartIndex; j<nEndIndex; j++)
{
    strTestTimeRecord[j] = [[NSString stringWithString:strPlog[j]] retain];
    [strPlog[j] release];
    strPlog[j] = nil;
}

[self showTestStatus:bTestStatus[nWellIndex] wellIndex:nWellIndex];

// Refresh UI to indicate test result
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(afterRun:) withObject:argument waitUntilDone:NO];
[pool release];
}



- (void)testThreadUUTRoutine:(id)argument
{ 
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; 

//Initialisation and etc
...

NSLog(@"UUT%d starts to run independently...", nUUTIndex+1);



// Run
for (int i=g_nIndependentStart; i<g_nIndependentStop; i++)
{       
    // Per Command Line
    CommandLine *cmdLine = [cmdArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *cmdName = [cmdLine valueForKey:@"cmdName"];
    NSString *cmdParam = [cmdLine valueForKey:@"cmdParam"];
    NSString *itemName = [cmdLine valueForKey:@"itemName"];


    if ([g_uutThread[nUUTIndex] isCancelled])
    {
        goto UUTTHREAD_EXIT;
    }



    if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_SKIP) {
        ...
        if (itemName != nil) {
            [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] testResult]
                       testItem:itemName uutIndex:nUUTIndex
                      uutStatus:SKIPPED];

        }
        continue;
    }




        // Before Item Test, save timestamp
        if (itemName != nil) {
            NSString* timeStamp = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"\n%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: " timeZone:nil locale:nil];
            //timeStamp1 = [NSDate date];
            [strPlog[nUUTIndex] appendFormat:@"%@ START %@", timeStamp, itemName];

        }

        // insert to UART log file
        char buff[1024];
        NSString *strInfo = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d: %@, (%@), %@", i, cmdName, cmdParam, itemName];
        sprintf(buff, "\n[Host Executing Cmd]%s\n", [strInfo UTF8String]);
        [self uartDataLogging:nUUTIndex buffer:buff pureUARTData:NO];


    if ([cmdName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"_If"] != NSOrderedSame &&
        [cmdName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"_Else"] != NSOrderedSame &&
        [cmdName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"_EndIf"] != NSOrderedSame &&
        [cmdName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"_Do..."] != NSOrderedSame &&
        [cmdName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"_While"] != NSOrderedSame) {
        [self parseCommand:cmdName parameter:cmdParam lineIndex:i uutIndex:nUUTIndex wellIndex:nWellIndex];
    }

    //_If, _ElseIf and _EndIf
    if ([cmdName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"_If"] == NSOrderedSame) {

        paramArray = [cmdParam componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        if ([paramArray count] != 2)
        {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                NSRunAlertPanel(@"Command Execution Error",
                                @"Incorrect parameter number for _If! Command Line %d Ignored!",
                                @"OK", nil, nil, i);
            });

            return;
        }

        int nIfLineNo = [[paramArray objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
        if ((nIfLineNo < 0) || (nIfLineNo >= i))
        {
            NSRunAlertPanel(@"Command Execution Error", @"_If statement at line %d has wrong parameter, %d!",
                            @"OK", nil, nil, i, nIfLineNo);
            continue;
        }


        int nElseLineNo = [[NSApp delegate] getElseLineNo:i];
        int nEndIfLineNo = [[NSApp delegate] getEndIfLineNo:i];
        int nNextStepNo = nEndIfLineNo; // By default jump to _EndIF
        if (nEndIfLineNo == -1)
        {
            NSRunAlertPanel(@"Command Execution Error",
                            @"_IF statement at line %d has no corresponding _ENDIF statement!",
                            @"OK", nil, nil, i);
            continue; // ignore this line
        }
        else if ((nElseLineNo != -1) && (nElseLineNo < nEndIfLineNo)) // Jump to _ELSE
        {
            nNextStepNo = nElseLineNo+1;
        }

        hasIf = TRUE;

        NSString *condition = [paramArray objectAtIndex:1];

        // Condition
        int nIfCondition;

        if ([condition rangeOfString:@"PASS" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location
            != NSNotFound)
        {
            nIfCondition = PASS;
        }
        else
        {
            nIfCondition = FAIL;
        }

        BOOL jumpToIf = FALSE;

        //for (j=StartIndex; j<EndIndex; j++)
        //{
            // Active UUT
        if (uutActive[nUUTIndex]) {

            CommandLine *cmdLine = [cmdArray objectAtIndex:nIfLineNo];
            if ([cmdLine lineStatus:nUUTIndex] == nIfCondition) {
                bIfElseFlag[nUUTIndex] = TRUE;
                jumpToIf = TRUE;

            }
            else {
                bIfElseFlag[nUUTIndex] = FALSE;

            }
        }

        if (!jumpToIf)
        {
            i = nNextStepNo-1;
        }
        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setCmdResult:@"_If"];
        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setTestResult:@"_If"];
        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setCmdStatus:PASS];


        continue;

    }

    if ([cmdName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"_Else"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        if ( ! hasIf)
        {
            NSRunAlertPanel(@"Command Execution Error",
                            @"ElseIf statement at step %d has no corresponding _IF statement!",
                            @"OK", nil, nil, i);
            continue;
        }

        BOOL bIfDone = TRUE;

        bIfElseFlag[nUUTIndex] = !bIfElseFlag[nUUTIndex];
        if (bIfElseFlag[nUUTIndex])
        {
            bIfDone = FALSE;
        }

        // No UUT jump to _ELSE. Jump directly to _EndIf
        if (bIfDone)
        {
            int nEndIfLineNo = [[NSApp delegate] getEndIfLineNo:i];
            if (nEndIfLineNo == -1)
            {
                NSRunAlertPanel(@"Command Execution Error",
                                @"_ElseIf statement at line %d has no corresponding _EndIf statement!",
                                @"OK", nil, nil, i);
                break; // Stop all UUT test
            }
            else
            {
                i = nEndIfLineNo-1;
            }
        }

        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setCmdResult:@"_Else"];
        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setTestResult:@"_Else"];
        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setCmdStatus:PASS];


        continue;
    }

    if ([cmdName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"_EndIf"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        if ( ! hasIf)
        {
            NSRunAlertPanel(@"Command Execution Error",
                            @"EndIf statement at line %d has no corresponding _IF statement!",
                            @"OK", nil, nil,  i);
            continue;
        }

        bIfElseFlag[nUUTIndex] = FALSE;

        hasIf = FALSE;

        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setCmdResult:@"_EndIf"];
        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setTestResult:@"_EndIf"];
        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setCmdStatus:PASS];


        continue;

    }


    //_Do... and _While
    if ([cmdName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"_Do..."] == NSOrderedSame) {
        g_nDoIndex[nUUTIndex] = i;
        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setCmdResult:@"_Do"];
        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setTestResult:@"_Do"];
        [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setCmdStatus:PASS];

        continue;
    }

    if ([cmdName caseInsensitiveCompare:@"_While"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        // Check validity
        if (g_nDoIndex[nUUTIndex] == -1)
        {
            NSRunAlertPanel(@"Command Execution Error",
                            @"_While statement at line %d has no corresponding _DO... statement!",
                            @"OK", nil, nil, i);
            continue;
        }

        paramArray = [cmdParam componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        if ([paramArray count] != 3)
        {
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
                NSRunAlertPanel(@"Command Execution Error",
                                @"Incorrect parameter number for _While! Command Line %d Ignored!",
                                @"OK", nil, nil, i);
            });

            return;
        }

        int lineNo = [[paramArray objectAtIndex:0]intValue];
        if ((lineNo < 0) || (lineNo >= i))
        {
            NSRunAlertPanel(@"Command Execution Error", @"_While statement at line %d has wrong parameter, %d!",
                            @"OK", nil, nil, i, lineNo);
            continue;
        }


        if (lineNo == -1)
        {
            NSRunAlertPanel(@"Command Execution Error",
                            @"_While statement at line %d has wrong parameter(%d)!",
                            @"OK", nil, nil, i, lineNo);
            continue;
        }

        NSString *condition = [paramArray objectAtIndex:1];

        // Condition
        int nWhileResult;

        if ([condition rangeOfString:@"PASS" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            nWhileResult = PASS;
        else if ([condition rangeOfString:@"FAIL" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
            nWhileResult = FAIL;
        else
            nWhileResult = UNKNOWN;

        // Loop if any UUT not pass
        BOOL bWhileLoop = FALSE;
            // Active UUT
        if (uutActive[nUUTIndex] &&  ! bUUTPass[nUUTIndex])
        {
            CommandLine *cmdLine = [cmdArray objectAtIndex:lineNo];
            if ([cmdLine lineStatus:nUUTIndex] == nWhileResult) {
                if (g_nLoopCount[nUUTIndex] < [[paramArray objectAtIndex:2] intValue])
                {
                    bWhileLoop = TRUE;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                bUUTPass[nUUTIndex] = TRUE; // No need to test this UUT anymore in this _DO..._While loop
            }

        }
        if (bWhileLoop)
        {
            i = g_nDoIndex[nUUTIndex];
            g_nLoopCount[nUUTIndex]++;
        }
        else
        {
            // Do...While loop finished
            g_nDoIndex[nUUTIndex] = -1;
            g_nLoopCount[nUUTIndex] = 1;
            bUUTPass[nUUTIndex] = FALSE;
        }
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setCmdResult:@"_While"];
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setTestResult:@"_While"];
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setCmdStatus:PASS];


        continue;

    }


        [self saveCmdReading:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] cmdResult]
                 commandLine:i uutIndex:nUUTIndex
                  lineStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] cmdStatus]];



    // Test Item
    if (itemName != nil)
    {

            [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] testResult]
                       testItem:itemName uutIndex:nUUTIndex uutStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] cmdStatus]];


        // After Item Test, save timestamp
        NSString* timeStamp = [[NSDate date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"\n%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S: " timeZone:nil locale:nil];


        [strPlog[nUUTIndex] appendFormat:@"%@ FINISH %@", timeStamp, itemName];

    }

    // Fail Stop/Abort
    if ([[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] cmdStatus] == FAIL)
    {
        if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_FAILSTOP)
        {
            // Stop this UUT test
            uutActive[nUUTIndex] = 0;

            if ([[uutBarcode objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] length] > 0) {
                [self InstantPudding_Done:nUUTIndex];

            }


            NSLog(@"UUT%d Fail and Stop Test!", nUUTIndex+1);
            goto UUTTHREAD_EXIT;
        }
        else if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_FAILABORT)
        {
            bTestStatus[nWellIndex] = ABORT;
          //  [loopPool drain];
            goto UUTTHREAD_EXIT;
        }
        else if ([cmdLine flag] & FLAG_APPLEPASS)
        {
            [[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] setCmdStatus:APPLEPASS];

             [self saveUutResult:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] testResult] testItem:itemName
                       uutIndex:nUUTIndex uutStatus:[[cmdReturn objectAtIndex:nUUTIndex] cmdStatus]];

        }
    }

    if (itemName != nil)
        g_itemCount[nUUTIndex]++;
}

UUTTHREAD_EXIT:

[pool release];
}
```

Comment: Most everyone looks at that code and... TL;DR. No one can debug that w/o trying to run it, and it sounds like it won't run without your omissions.  That said, are you aware that you can [Suspend a thread in Xcode?](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-debug_navigator/articles/suspending_a_thread.html)  Something is blocking the main thread.  I also find it useful just to pause and look at what the call stack is when there's a hang. And make sure you look at the *entire* stack, not just what XCode shows by default.

Comment: Thanks stevesliva. Thanks a lot for the useful comment. I suspended the thread in Xcode as suggested and noticed that there are a couple of [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:X] and 1 [testTable01 display] running at the same time. I removed 1 of the [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:X]s and the app UI seems to work fine already although it causes other issues in my App. By the way, is there any other good way to do delay in Cocoa without using [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:X]? I am also wondering why [testTable01 display] always "grabbing" the thread.